# pick up files based on dates in ksh script

Tags: shell, unix

I have this list of files .  Now I will have to pick the latest file based on some condition

```
   3679 Jul 21 23:59 belk_rpo_error_**po9324892**_07212014.log
   0    Jul 22 23:59 belk_rpo_error_**po9324892**_07222014.log
   3679 Jul 23 23:59 belk_rpo_error_**po9324892**_07232014.log
     22 Jul 22 06:30 belk_rpo_error_**po9324267**_07012014.log
      0 Jul 20 05:50 belk_rpo_error_**po9999992**_07202014.log
    411 Jul 21 06:30 belk_rpo_error_**po9999992**_07212014.log
    742 Jul 21 07:30 belk_rpo_error_**po9999991**_07212014.log
      0 Jul 23 2014  belk_rpo_error_**po9999991**_07232014.log
```

For a PATRICULAR Order_No(Marked with ** **)

1. If the latest file is 0 kB then we will discard it (rest of the files with same Order_no as well)
2. if the latest file is non Zero then I will take it.(Only the latest one)

Then append the contents in a txt file .
My expected output would be ::

```
   411 Jul 21 06:30 belk_rpo_error_**po9999992**_07212014.log
   3679 Jul 23 23:59 belk_rpo_error_**po9324892**_07232014.log
    22 Jul 22 06:30 belk_rpo_error_**po9324267**_07012014.log
```

I am at my wits end here. I cant seem to figure out how to compare dates in Unix. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: The latest mean latest in time not latest in line number in your list ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
touch test.txt
for var in ` find . ! -empty -exec ls -r {} \;`
do
    cat $var>>test.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

untested

use `stat` to emit date (epoch time), size and filename.
use `awk` to filter out zero-length files  and extract order number.
sort by order number and date
`awk` to pick up the last filename for each order number

```
stat -c $'%Y\t%s\t%n' *.log | 
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    $2 > 0 {
        split($3, a, /_/)
        print a[4], $1, $3
    }' |
sort -t $'\t' -k1,1 -k2,2n |
awk -F'\t' '
    NR > 1 && $1 != prev_order {print filename}
    {filename = $3; prev_order = $1}
    END {print filename}
'
```

The sort command might be wrong: In order to group by order number, you might need to sort first by file time *then* by order number.

If I understand your question, the resulting files need to be concatenated and appended to a file. If the above pipeline is working OK, then pipe into `| xargs cat >> something.log`